# How can I see questions about "java" -- no, I mean really about *java*?

Tags: discussion, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I like to peruse all the questions about the Java language, class libraries, JVM, etc., in part to learn about these things and in part because I have decent expertise on many of these areas to share.

But when I subscribe to the "java" tag in my feed reader, I'm absolutely inundated with questions that aren't really *about* Java -- examples:

- Questions about Spring
- Questions about XML (where the user irrelevantly is also using Java)
- Questions specific to EJB, JDBC, Hibernate, Swing, the Facebook Java API etc. etc. -- see, if I wanted to see those things, I'd be looking for *those* tags!
- Questions about how to learn C++ .. if you're a Java programmer
- Questions about how this bit of Java code would be written in Python

and the list just goes on, and on, and on.  It's quite a flood of stuff that I don't care about.

How can I find just the questions that are really **about Java**?  Do we need a new tag, like `plainjava` or `justjava`?  Or, should people with an EJB question (and `ejb` tag) just not be adding the `java` tag as well?  Or am I just out of luck?  Thanks.

**EDIT:** so far, all the answers given require me to keep maintaining a list of all the specific technologies I'm uninterested in. But this isn't really an issue of what I'm *not* interested in; what I *am* interested in is simply questions that are *about Java*, as opposed to *related to Java*. Isn't there a better way?

To illustrate how this is not a great solution, the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20-swing%20-eclipse%20-hibernate%20-spring%20-jsp%20-servlets%20-tomcat%20-j2ee%20-jdbc%20-jpa%20-android%20-gui%20-beginner%20-applet%20-netbeans%20-c%23%20-xml%20-maven-2%20-.net%20-jsf%20-j2me%20-windows%20-gwt%20-ant%20-jboss%20-php%20-google-app-engine%20-python%20-jar%20-database%20-javascript%20-c%2b%2b

... doesn't even seem to work.  But if I remove one excluded tag from it, then it does.  Seems like I'm overflowing the site's capabilities.

**EDIT EDIT:** Groan! Even with filtering all these most-popular tags out, the ten most recent posts are still about: Spring, Java, Unicode, Cold Fusion, Servlets, HTML, SOAP, Apache-Poi, Java, MySQL!  This seems hopeless unless some kind of "justjava" tag is introduced...

Comment: I see you are trying to read about Java. You should totally drop that and use jQuery.

Comment: So do you want people to avoid the `java` tag if the question is about something that depends on Java (e.g. JACOB, Swing) but not about the language itself?

Comment: I don't "want people" to do anything; I don't have the answer here, just the question.

It's an interesting failure of the tag system that there is this whole, very important topic area -- the Java platform -- that's virtually impossible to subscribe to.

Comment: Related: [Congratulations Eric Lippert for finally winning the \[c#-language\] badge!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62669)

Answer (score 8):

Add `java` and `jvm` to your list of Interesting tags, and add `spring`, `xml`, `ejb`, `jdbc`, etc. to your Ignore list.  Then go check the "Hide Ignored Tags" box on the prefs tab of your profile.

Comment: Seems like a stopgap solution though.

Comment: @Pacerier It's been over four years.

Comment: but the problem is still not fixed right?

Comment: @Pacerier There's nothing to fix. The solution was there all along. Follow tags you like and ignore tags you don't want to see.

Comment: Ok I know that, but the question has stated that it's generally a stopgap solution. The crux of it is that he would have to add a never-ending constantly-increasing amount of tags to ignore, instead of simply have an option to e.g. follow the tag "plainjava".

Comment: @Pacerier How real a concern do you think that is? You might have to add a new tag to ignore every 6 months or so. That's a lot more workable than expecting every Java programmer to know about and use the "plainjava" tag and not use any other tags.

Comment: I'm obviously not suggesting the use of the "plainjava" tag. I'm saying the system should be reworked to easily provide a way to view questions that are "plainjava".

Comment: @Pacerier How are you not suggesting that? The example that you gave was exactly that. A hand-wavy "rework the system" is not a solution. My answer is.

Comment: It's an *example* to illustrate the idea. Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36695/how-can-i-see-questions-about-java-no-i-mean-really-about-java#comment-83988

Answer (score 7):

Promoting sth's comment and my follow-up comment to an answer, you can filter out certain tags by preceding them with "-".  For example:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java -ejb -jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20-ejb%20-jdbc)

You can get feeds the same way:

[https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/java -ejb -jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/java%20-ejb%20-jdbc)

Comment: Is manually modifying the URL the official way to do this?

Comment: @KevinBourrillion: it's the only way I know of to do it. It may be one of those expensive features that they don't want to advertise.

Answer (score 2):

It would be interesting if you could create a Boolean expression for tags.  Like: `java and not ejb and not jdbc`

Comment: You can do that for the "tags" view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20-ejb%20-jdbc

Comment: @sth, cool - did not know that (obviously)

Comment: @sth: you can even do a feed this way: `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/java+-ejb+-jdbc` http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/java+-ejb+-jdbc

Comment: note that it's tricky to represent C# and C++ in the url.  I figured it out, but... direct URL hacking is not a UI.